# Taylor theorem for a multivariate BV function

Tags: analysis, taylor-expansion, bounded-variation

Given a function $f(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n):\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ which is in $BV(\Omega)$ and has, in $\textbf{0}$, all partial derivatives up to order $n-1$, all equal to 0:
$$
\frac{\partial^{|\alpha|} f}{\partial \textbf{x}^\alpha}(\textbf{0})=0,\quad |\alpha|<n,
$$

can anything be said about the existence of $f_{x_1x_2\cdots x_n}(\textbf{0})$?

My dream would be to get a Taylor-like expression of the form
$$
   f(\textbf{x})=0 + 0 + \ldots + 0 + \bar f\Delta x_1\cdots \Delta x_n+o(|\textbf{x}|^{n}).
$$
since all terms of lower order cancel, and that $BV$ must be worth something :)

If not, any minimal additional hypothesis that might be required?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

General remark:   $BV$ is worth something when you deal with first-order derivatives. It says that first-order derivatives are measures. 
This does not help much with higher-order pointwise expansions.

You neglected the possibility that variables can be repeated in monomials of $n$th degree. For example, 
even the polynomial $f(\mathbf x) = x_1^n$ does not admit an expansion of your kind, because the $n$th 
degree term here is $x_1^n$, not $x_1\dots x_n$.

If you include other $n$th degree monomials, the answer is still no. 
The function $f(\mathbf x)=x_1|x_2|$ is in $BV$ (furthermore, is Lipschitz), its first-order derivatives exist and vanish at $0$. But it cannot be approximated by a polynomial up to  $o(|\mathbf x|^2)$.

Apart from the familiar theorems about finite Taylor expansions, I don't think you'll find a hypothesis that is easier to 
check in practice than the asymptotic expansion itself.

Comment: Ok, I definitely should look for my own (very simple) counterexamples before bothering other people :)

Thanks!